have trouble getting error traces detail on opentelemetry
I cant get error traces detail on zipkin my infra looks like that
my tomcat side
in
added this conf for attach opentelemetry autoinsttrumental agent 

export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/usr/local/apache_tomcats/tomcat1/opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar \
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint="http://172.17.92.181:4317" \
-Dotel.traces.exporter=otlp \
-Dotel.metrics.exporter=otlp \
-Dotel.instrumentation.http.status_code.error=400-599 \
-Dotel.resource.attributes=service.name=MEHMETTESTTOMCAT"

and my collector side looks like that
cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"  # Adjust heap size as needed
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
      # Add more xpack features you want to disable, if any
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"  # This port is used for communication between nodes (not needed for single-node setup)
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.15.2
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200  # Linking Kibana to Elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"  # Kibana port

        #  fluentbit:
        #    image: fluent/fluent-bit:latest
        #    container_name: fluentbit
        #    volumes:
        #      - ./fluent-bit.conf:/fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf
        #    depends_on:
        #      - elasticsearch
        #

  fluentbit:
     image: fluent/fluent-bit:latest
     container_name: fluentbit
     volumes:
       - ./fluent-bit.conf:/fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  # Mount Docker socket for access to container logs
     depends_on:
       - elasticsearch


  otel-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.97.0
    container_name: otel-collector
    ports:
      - "4317-4318:4317-4318"
      - "55679:55679"
      - "8888:8888"
      - "8889:8889"
      - "24224:24224"
      - "3030:3030"
    environment:
      OTLP_EXPORTER_ENDPOINT: "http://172.17.92.181:14268/api/traces"
    volumes:
      - ./otel-collector.yml:/etc/otel-collector.yml
    command: --config=/etc/otel-collector.yml
    restart: unless-stopped

  java-demoapp-jagger:
    #image: java-demoapp-with-exporter
    image: java-demoapp-jagger
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9100:9100"
  zipkingui:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin:latest
    container_name: zipkingui
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"

  prometheus:
    image: quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.49.1
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command: --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml


      #  loki:
      #    image: grafana/loki:latest
      #    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml
      #    ports:
      #      - "3100:3100"
      #
      #  tempo:
      #    image: grafana/tempo:latest
      #    command: [ "-config.file=/etc/tempo.yml" ]
      #    volumes:
      #      - ./tempo.yml:/etc/tempo.yml
      #    ports:
      #      - "3200:3200"   # tempo
      #      - "4317"  # otlp grpc

  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana
    volumes:
      - ./grafana-datasources.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasources.yml
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  jaeger-all-in-one:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "16686:16686"
      - "14250:14250"

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local


and its working fine for normal succesfull requests
like that


and my problem is i cant get error traces detail like that
foreaxmple my project dosnt have non-exsit end point and if im get reqest this endpoint im getting 404

and in zipkin im seeing like that  no detail what is response code which request was maded

if you know can u explain what im missing and how can i  solve that  ?
